# PageAsyncTask vs just calling await

Tags: asp.net, .net, async-await

I'm a bit confused about the usage around ASP .NET's built in `PageAsyncTask` object.

Does it provide an advantage over just using the built in .NET `await` symantics? Am I mistaken in thinking that just calling `await` will release the thread to handle additional incoming requests or do I have to use `PageAsyncTask` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how ASP.NET WebForms work. The only way to run code asynchronously is using a `PageAsyncTask`.

[What not to do in ASP.NET, and what to do instead - Asynchronous Page Events with Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet-and-what-to-do-instead#asyncevents)